# Github Pages not showing index.html

Tags: html, github, github-pages

I just pushed the page index.html to `gh-pages` and when I look at the status in settings it says this:

```
Your site is ready to be published at http://fireflysemantics.github.io/help.serviceparts/.
```

This is the link:

http://fireflysemantics.github.io/help.serviceparts/

and this is the repository:

https://github.com/fireflysemantics/help.serviceparts

However I get a 404 when I visit the link.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `index.html` must have the essential HTML tags so that it renders as a webpage. Try modifying your HTML document to contain the following snippet:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<title>help.serviceparts</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Hello</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are making a github page for a project (since the name of the repository does not match your username) you have to go to settings of the repository, scroll down to "GitHub Pages" and select the branch you want to use.